# Drag Image in a Window Phone 7+ Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7.5 Silverlight app

I want to let the user drag the image on the page within a restricted area. 
This image is within a Grid that has other elements.

I will be using GestureListener and have even tried implementing. Below is the code. I have tried after reading few sample articles.

```
<Image x:Name="imgFootball"  Margin="55,108,55,1" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Ball.png" Height="250" Width="250">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"></toolkit:GestureListener>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="imgImageTranslate" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
            imgImageTranslate.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
            imgImageTranslate.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
}
```

Now using the above code the dragging **works fine.**

[image]

**My Problem (Updated 01/19):** I want to set the limit for the dragging area . i.e. I want to add drag to Circle and Triangle. They are allowed to be dragged over other shapes but cannot go over the TextBlocks or the arrows in the corner. All the elements are currently in the Grid.

I tried suggestion as mentioned by Chris and used StackPanel. It limits the behavior but then I am not able to position the elments as shown i.e. in a scattered places. Instead the SP forces me to stack them one over the other Vertically or horizontally. Also other shapes have their own animation like resizing, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get an easier result by attaching a MouseDragElementBehavior to the object and setting its ConstrainToParentBounds property so it will respect the bounds of its Parent object like a Grid or Border or something. Refer here [http://microsoftfeed.com/2011/how-to-add-mousedragelementbehavior-in-windows-phone-7/][1][1]: http://microsoftfeed.com/2011/how-to-add-mousedragelementbehavior-in-windows-phone-7//

*****Example showing how just the two elements you named drag within the parent boundries bevause you only have the Behavior attached to those specific objects.;

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:el="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
    x:Class="WindowsPhonetester.PhonePage1"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFF50606" BorderThickness="3" Margin="9,141,8,174">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFF35206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" Margin="20,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
            </Border>
            <Path Data="M43,98 L21,111 L41,124 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="20.5,97.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23"/>
            <Path Data="M406,103 L406,125 L429,113 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0,102.5,26.5,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24"/>
            <TextBlock Height="28" Margin="108,98,112,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF0635F3" Height="79" Margin="164,181,204,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Ellipse>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF3DF06" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="64" Margin="0,181,26,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123"/>
            <Path Data="M78,318 L41,383 L111,380 z" Fill="#FFF306DF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Margin="40.5,0,0,223.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="71">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Path>
            <Path Data="M275,309 L322,305 L357,327 L362,360 L342,391 L295,398 L259,376 L252,338 z" Fill="#FF06F30A" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="94" Margin="0,0,93.5,208.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="111"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Setting Bound as Grid is preventing the element to go outside of the screen, and that's fine. But that actually doesn't help as I want to avoid dragging on some elements that's inside the same grid Row. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand, if the behavior is attached to the object you want to be allowed to drag, it shouldn't allow any other objects to be dragged even if in the Parent boundary?

Comment: I meant my element was dragging on my TextBlock element which I didn't want. But actually I was able to make it work by separating my elements by putting it inside the StackPanel. Although I would love to learn doing similar using Gesture Service.

Comment: Actually StackPanel won't work I think as the controls inside it are either horizontally or vertically stacked. Correct me if I am wrong. I tried to wrap a SP around my controls and now they are all misaligned like stacked vertically.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding, is the Stack Panel the thing you're trying to give MouseDrag behavior to? Yes, a StackPanel has a default alignment or you can do Orientation="Horizontal" to organized objects contained in it horizontally. If there's a specific object within that SP you want to move while the others stay fixed, just take it out of the SP and move it to the front...if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have updated my question. Hope that will make more sense now. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hey Oms, Ya you can't combine all the elements within a stackpanel, the draggable content items will have to be broken out and margin's used for first placement depending how they're organized and a z-index may need to be set. I can make an example likely later tonight when I get off work to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. I would love to see an example. I am going to keep trying different ways to make this work.

Comment: Sorry it took so long Oms, ran into other circumstances that required my attention before I could flop this out for you. Give it a shot. The non-moving elements can be organized however you like, the behavior though has to be attached to an object able to move freely within the parent bounds like shown in the example code I added to my answer. Cheers

Comment: Thank you Chris. I will give it a try. Although I did come up with something similar where I wrapped my shapes inside a Canvas. Nesting Grid didn't come to my mind. I will have to talk to the designer to restucture and try your code. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No worries, I made that in about 5 minutes so there wasn't a lot of effort put forth but hopefully it helps, if you run into anything else just say so and we'll see what we can come up with.

Comment: May be you can share your thoughts on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977672/need-clarification-on-using-audio-on-button-click-background-audio-etc-in-wind