# Windows Phone 7.5 XAP Package Size requirement

Tags: silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7.1/7.5/Mango Silverlight App.

Coming from here: [Need clarification on using audio on button click, background audio, etc in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977672/need-clarification-on-using-audio-on-button-click-background-audio-etc-in-wind)

Our designer will be converting all the mp3s to .wav files. Done few and they are coming to about 200kb each.
The current estimate is we might have like 100+ of those for our app.

I know the Certification Requirment is:

> The maximum size of the XAP package file is 225 MB.

Designer said he will try to compress them down to about 100kb making sure sound quality is ok as well.

Though I am sure we won't exceed 225MB but I think lesser is better as it will affect the download time on the device as well. Don't want the user to quit download halfway.
I read somewhere there is some time restiction as well for certification.

Is this acceptable, or am I missing any other strategies for keeping my audio files small other than compression?  Are there any other considerations I need to take into account when certifying a large app?

Comment: Is the requirement for the total size to be less than 225MB or just any one XAP file to be less than this? If it's the latter you can break your application into separate XAP files.

Comment: @ChrisF how do you have multiple XAP files per application?

Comment: Well unless it's something they've blocked for phone applications you can select the "Reduce XAP size by using application library caching" option.

Comment: @ChrisF: What I understand is there's only one XAP file that VS outputs per app.  I don't understand "break your app" part.

Comment: It might not be available for phone apps, but see my previous comment about the "reduce XAP size" option.

Comment: @Chris: I see not for WP apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, download times don't largely affect conversion rates, because they download in the background. I'll frequently download a few apps, then check back on them the next day or so.

Comment: On the contarary, I started downloading app and it was taking long. It wasn't a good exprience. So I mentioned it in my question. I also saw there is Over-the-air limit of 20MB. So my app will have to be downloaded via wifi or cabled connection.

Comment: @oms Correct, it's not a good experience, you want to make it as small as possible, but it won't really affect conversion rates. They'll probably just start using it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the number of video files and resources together shouldn't exceed 2000 files (Plus the size requirement of course). I had a lot of issues in my experience with submitting xap packages that contains a lot of files. The last app was a video dictionary that contains more than 2000 video files all with tiny size but that didn't work well, though the size was just 90 Mega bytes, the responses from the support are slow and we had to wait each time to finally find that we had to respect this rule which is not documented

Comment: Interesting. So did you ever find any reference of this on AppHub forums or anywhere? For now I don't see we going above 2000 files but who knows. Just confirming that 2000 limit includes images and audio files which has buildAction=Content correct?

Comment: nope, we had to find ourselves and the most weird thing is that the automated validation processor after submission returns an obscure error message that confused us, the guys on the app hub reporting the same message error had different issues.